# Need help understand independent identically distributed random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be three independent, identically distributed random variables
each with density function 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3x^2 & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $Y=\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$. Find $P(Y\gt \frac{1}{2}).$  Answer key $\frac{511}{512}$

Now the author has not defined what identically distributed random variables are so I looked it up and found:

- Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are **identically distributed** if for every set $A\in S$ $P(X\in A)=P(Y \in A)$.

Using this I used the following reasoning

- WLOG let $Y=\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}=X_1$
- because one of the $X_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ has to be the max
- and since $P\left(X_1>\frac{1}{2}\right)=P\left(X_2>\frac{1}{2}\right)=P\left(X_3 > \frac{1}{2}\right)$

then 
$$P(Y >\frac{1}{2})=P(X_1>\frac{1}{2})=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 3x^2 \, dx= \left.x^3 \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1=1-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{8}.$$
I kind of had a suspicion of the answer being wrong since I did not use independence at all but I guess I do not understand what the question is actually trying to get me to figure out. Now after seeing the solution I have noticed that somehow they must have got $$P(Y>0.5)=\left.x^9\vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right|_{0.5}^1 = \frac{511}{512}$$ but why I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a dice and $X_1$ (or $X_2,X_3$ it doesn't matter since they are iid) as the result of one toss. Then, it is clear that the result of $X_1$ is not the same as doing $X_1$ three times and taking the maximum result !

Now, mathematicaly, you need to calculate $P(Y>1/2)=P(\max(X_i)>1/2)$. But the saying that the max of three numbers is greather than a $1/2$ (or any quantity) doesn't give you much information, only that there is at least one of the $X_i$ greater than $1/2$, whereas the opposite event gives : $1-P(Y>1/2) = P(Y<1/2) = P(X_1 < 1/2, X_2 < 1/2, X_3 < 1/2)$. And then you can use independence to calculate your probability.

Comment: thanks it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

The probability the maximum is $\gt 1/2$ is $1$ minus the probability the maximum is $\le 1/2$.

And the maximum is $\le 1/2$ if and only if $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are **all** $\le 1/2$.

By independence the probability they are all $\le 1/2$ is $(1/2^3)^3$. This is $\frac{1}{512}$.

*Remark*: The fact that the $X_i$ all have the same distribution does not play a crucial role. If they had different distributions, we could still find the probability that $Y\le 1/2$ by computing $\Pr(X_1\le 1/2)\Pr(X_2\le 1/2)\Pr(X_3\le 1/2)$. However,  the *independence* is crucial, for that is what allows us to multiply.

Comment: @user101388: You are welcome.